# Vertically align fixed element which is rotated?

Tags: html, css, css-position, css-transforms

I'm using the position property to position a button which triggers the menu on the left side, I also want it in the center of the page on the y-axis, the problem is that the element is rotated -90deg and there is a whitespace on the left now. I dont want to position it dirty left: -24px; or something. Do someone know why there is a whitespace and if yes, how can I prevent this to happend and solve my issue?

Here is my code, which you can also find in a codepen I've made:

```
<div class="content-wrapper bg--secondary">
    <div class="menu__button">
        <span class="menu__button__link">
            menu
        </span>
    </div>  
</div>


// CSS starts here

.content-wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

.menu__button{
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0%;
    transform: translate(0%, -50%) rotate(-90deg);
}

.bg--primary{
    background-color: #2d2d2d;
}
```

Click [here](https://codepen.io/Lueh/pen/awGgpd) to visit the codepen, I think it's easier to understand in the environment.

Comment: Most of us who don't use SCSS won't be able to help you if you don't supply the compiled CSS.

Comment: Okay, sorry for that, thought most people are understanding SASS or SCSS today. I will change the code snippet.

Comment: I've adjusted my answer to better explain what is happening here - have a look and let me know if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fix your problem is to adjust the `transform-origin` of your menu button.

```
.menu-button {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: 100px 25px; //the height of the element and the height - the center position (explanation below);
}
```

I've adjusted it inside your [codepen as an example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OgZKRY).

As a further explanation as to why this is happening to your menu, your `transform-origin` is always `center center` so if your element is 150px wide, it's center is 75px away from the left of the screen.

After you rotate the element, the center is still 75px away from the screen, even though your "new width" is the height of your menu button, which in this case is 100px, with a center of 50px, which leaves 25px of space between your element and the side of the screen.